# Controlling position of popup form on continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Summary of issue: 
My objective was to use a control event on my continuous form to open a small popup form horizontally aligned with the record selected in the continuous form giving the user a selection of other actions they can quickly perform on the selected record.

To establish the 'top' value for the sub form I planned to use the height of the continuous form control (300) multiplied by the record number returned using the form.SelTop property (eg 3 for the 3rd record). This should in my mind give me an accurate 'top' value for my popup form.

This works well aside from an unacceptable horizontal alignment issue on all but 1 of the records (10th record for some reason). The amount of misalignment is not a constant number but appears to be +/- 10% (of the 300 unit height) depending on whether moving up or down the dataset.

Any help appreciated :(

Comment: Your idea, while a good one, is bending Access the wrong way. I have poured hundreds of wasted hours into getting a reliable version of this idea to work. The vagaries of the Form event system drove me bonkers. (I am a competent professional who earns a living programming Access). 

So, I suggest giving up. Instead, make a continuous form, and add a combo box or buttons to show the extra actions. Not as pretty as your idea, but easy to do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Kismert. I have done as you suggested and made do with a button for now. With a bit of styling its not as ugly as i thought it would be so will roll with this for now.